# Microsoft Office 16.0 Access database engine Object Library and Microsoft Access 16.0 Object Library are missing from Macbook. Are they available?

Tags: vba, macos, ms-access

I want to use VBA in Excel to run an Access query that retrieves a small item of data, and I would like it to work cross platform in both Windows (which is OK) and Mac (which is not). The above references are missing on the Mac. If they don't exist, is there a way I can solve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortnatly there is no MS-Access for the Mac OS system.

And while many a develoeprs don't install MS-Access, they often say install ONLY the ms-access database engine called JET (now called ACE).

And, once again, there is no version of the JET/ACE data engine available for the MAC OS.

So, unless you run windows as some type of VM, and thus you not running Mac OS anymore, you simply don't have use of ms-access, and you don't have use of the Access database engine from VBA products that run on Mac OS.

So, no, this can't be done.